# SpringBoot - making jar files - No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot

Everything was working fine when starting my app using [IntelliJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IntelliJ_IDEA). But when I made a fat jar and executed it with

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

I got this:

```
16:37:44.194 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [pl.mypackage.Main]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:489)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:191)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
        at pl.mypackage.Main.main(Main.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:276)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.getCandidateConfigurations(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:84)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:481)
        ... 14 common frames omitted
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [pl.mypackage.Main]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:489)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:191)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:681)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:523)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:369)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:313)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
        at pl.mypackage.Main.main(Main.java:39)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:276)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.getCandidateConfigurations(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:145)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.selectImports(EnableAutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:84)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:481)
        ... 14 more
```

It looks like it doesn't found auto configuration classes in `META-INF/spring.factories`. How to add it, and what should be the content of this file?

Comment: How did you make your fat jar?

Comment: I had the same problem because I removed the `spring-boot-starter-parent` from my pom.xml and was making the jar using the assembly plugin like I am used to. Mea culpa. Using `spring-boot-starter-parent` works like a charm and find the correct main class automatically.

Answer (score 76):

I had the same problem and just solved it.

At first, I was generating the fat jar with the `maven-assembly-plugin`, which created a file called `mavenproject1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`. This file gave the same problem as you mentioned when I tried running it.

I think that because it's a Spring Boot application, you need to use their plug-in. I changed my packaging to the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and it generates two files: `mavenproject1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` and `mavenproject1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar.original`. Just try `java -jar target/mavenproject1-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar`, and it will hopefully work. :-)

For reference, here is my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.company</groupId>
    <artifactId>mavenproject1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-files</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> 
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                      <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                      </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
              <configuration>
                <archive>
                  <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <mainClass>com.company.mavenproject1.MainClass</mainClass>
                  </manifest>
                </archive>
                <descriptorRefs>
                  <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
              </configuration>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <id>assemble-all</id>
                  <phase>package</phase>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>single</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
              </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that <packaging>jar</packaging> in pom.xml is necessary. Without it you can still run the application in your IDE, but .jar will not work.

Comment: Worked for me! I'm using Spring Boot 2.0

Comment: What is the build command you are using after making these changes? mvn clean install? mvn package? Or something else?

Comment: @Benoit Larochelle what's the gradle version solution for this issue?

Comment: what if I cannot use `spring-boot-starter-parent` as parent?

Comment: @Benoit Larochelle Is it just me, or do you need to define the start-class property to make this work?

Comment: Build command to use here :  mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage

Comment: Why would you want to put `addClasspath=true` here? I would have thought you **wouldn't** want to add the classpath to the manifest if you are building a fat jar?

Comment: I was missing `spring-boot-configuration-processor`. If someone faces the same problem, this dependency might fix it.

Answer (score 32):

This is the solution :

1. add only plugin in POM.xml

   ```
   <build>
   <plugins>
      <plugin>
           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <configuration>
               <fork>true</fork>
               <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
           </configuration>
             <executions>
               <execution>
                 <goals>
                   <goal>repackage</goal>
                 </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   </plugins>
   ```
2. One property in pom.xml

   ```
   <properties>
     <start-class>com.xxx.yyy.MainClass</start-class>
   </properties>
   ```
3. Run command

   ```
   mvn clean package spring-boot:repackage
   ```
4. Now run your jar (it includes all dependencies now) created inside target folder

   ```
   java -jar my-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
   ```

Answer (score 14):

This configuration works for me. I execute my JAR as a service but the line is:

```
javaw -jar MY_JAR.jar
```

**POM**:

```
<properties>
        <!-- Spring boot main class -->
        <start-class>com.PATH_TO_MAIN.Main</start-class>
</properties>
...
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

With Spring Boot, it is no longer necessary to use the assembly-plugin. Do not forget to call the **package** goal.

Here is the [documentation example](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-maven-plugin.html).

Comment: This does not seem to work if the spring application is just another dependency within another standalone jar.

Answer (score 14):

Alternatively, if you cannot use the spring boot plugin for whatever reason, you can include the following file in your application. It should be called `src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories`:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/1.5.x/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories

This will work for spring boot 1.x and is helpful if you want to use spring managed beans in a REPL.

Comment: The file doesn't exist any more.

Comment: @peterh as of what version? It is present as of 1.5.4.

Comment: Thanks @peterh. Looks like they removed that file from spring boot 2, I've updated the answer to reflect that.

Comment: New location for this file is at https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/2.1.x/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories

Comment: How do we add it?

Answer (score 12):

For those of us new to IntelliJ, Spring, and Maven:

If you want to build a jar in IntelliJ, chances are you are using IntelliJ's build system: build, build artifacts, etc. However, that's not Maven. What you need is for Maven - not IntelliJ - to build it for you. To do this, you want to bring up the Maven panel in IntelliJ (under View => Tool Windows => Maven toward the bottom), and double click "package". Voila!

Comment: In my case, this is the answer.

Comment: This works for me too. In other words, you want to build the jar with Maven, not with Intellij. You may achieve the same result with just building the jar with the maven command `mvn package` in your project directory.

Comment: @kohane15 Correct. However, the specific Windows environment I was forced to use prevented me from accessing the `mvn` tools from the command prompt, so I had to stick with IntelliJ. I suspect that there would be others who may operate under the same constraint.

Answer (score 11):

I have added this configuration in my pom and the issue got resolved:

```
<build>
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 4):

Below POM works for me , this will allow you to have assembelled package with all dependency involved.

Add this at the start of your POM

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.xyz.test</groupId>
<artifactId>test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<name>test</name>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</parent>
```

Add this plugin

```
           <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <mainClass>com.xyz.test</mainClass>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

command to run

1. To check run - `mvn spring-boot:run`
2. to make fat jar - `mvn clean package`
3. to run jar - `java -jar /target/jar-file-name.jar`

Answer (score 2):

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
```

From above it seems that your packageing is not properly done. I know I'm late but it might help someone else.

**Solution**

Please check your `@SpringBootApplication` class shoud have base package all above the other classes. For example, let's your class `@SpringBootApplication` is inside a package `com.sb.foo` then all other spring stereotype classes should goes inside `com.sb.foo.xxx` where `xxx` can be anything. It can be further sub package `com.sb.foo.xxx.yyy`. This is a functionality of SpringBoot to enable Auto Configuration. This auto configuration works fine with IDE's like `Intellij` or `Eclipse` even if you have made the mistake.

The chances of facing such problem will be more if you're not using any building tool or recommeded IDEs like `STS eclipse` for development.

Answer (score 1):

You could add the spring.factories file to your META-INF folder. The spring.factories file for Spring version 2.0.4 is located here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.0.4.RELEASE/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories

Comment: Tried to add spring.factories file, but in resulted jar file it is not included, may I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

spring.factories is loaded by the AutoConfigurationImportSelector class in spring-boot-autoconfigure. This walks the context classloader for all resources of type META-INF/spring.factories.

To get spring boot to work after shading the jar, I simulated the same by merging the contents of all available spring.factories files into a single spring.factories file in my own jar's META-INF folder.

Here's my current spring.factories file:

```
# Initializers
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SharedMetadataReaderFactoryContextInitializer,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer

# Application Listeners
org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.BackgroundPreinitializer

# Auto Configuration Import Listeners
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportListener=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionEvaluationReportAutoConfigurationImportListener

# Auto Configuration Import Filters
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportFilter=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnClassCondition

# Auto Configure
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.admin.SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.aop.AopAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cassandra.CassandraAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cloud.CloudAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.MessageSourceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.couchbase.CouchbaseAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.dao.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.cassandra.CassandraRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.CouchbaseDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.couchbase.CouchbaseRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.jpa.JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.ldap.LdapDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.ldap.LdapRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.mongo.MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.neo4j.Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.neo4j.Neo4jRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.solr.SolrRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.redis.RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.rest.RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.data.web.SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.elasticsearch.jest.JestAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.gson.GsonAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.h2.H2ConsoleAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hateoas.HypermediaAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hazelcast.HazelcastAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.hazelcast.HazelcastJpaDependencyAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.integration.IntegrationAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jackson.JacksonAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.XADataSourceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JmsAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.activemq.ActiveMQAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.artemis.ArtemisAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jersey.JerseyAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jooq.JooqAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ldap.embedded.EmbeddedLdapAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.ldap.LdapAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.liquibase.LiquibaseAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mail.MailSenderValidatorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mobile.DeviceResolverAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mobile.DeviceDelegatingViewResolverAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mobile.SitePreferenceAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.embedded.EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mongo.MongoAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.reactor.ReactorAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.FallbackWebSecurityAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.OAuth2AutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.sendgrid.SendGridAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.session.SessionAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.social.SocialWebAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.social.FacebookAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.social.LinkedInAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.social.TwitterAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.solr.SolrAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.TransactionAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.transaction.jta.JtaAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.validation.ValidationAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebClientAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.WebSocketAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.websocket.WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.webservices.WebServicesAutoConfiguration

# Failure analyzers
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalyzer=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.diagnostics.analyzer.NoSuchBeanDefinitionFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceBeanCreationFailureAnalyzer,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.HikariDriverConfigurationFailureAnalyzer

# Template availability providers
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.template.TemplateAvailabilityProvider=\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.freemarker.FreeMarkerTemplateAvailabilityProvider,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.mustache.MustacheTemplateAvailabilityProvider,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.groovy.template.GroovyTemplateAvailabilityProvider,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.thymeleaf.ThymeleafTemplateAvailabilityProvider,\
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.JspTemplateAvailabilityProvider
```

Comment: Added the code you described to the already existing code in spring.factories file. In the end, I just got another error

Cannot instantiate interface org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextInitializer : org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging.AutoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem:

```
IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories.
```

with Java 9, spring boot 2.0.0, springboot-javafx-support 2.1.6.
I tried both maven and gradle 4 on the same project.

For me the fix was packaging the jar with java 8.

Comment: i am using java 8 only still this error is coming. please let me know if you have some updates regarding this.

Comment: Sorry Raj, haven't touch Java recently, so I don't have any update.

Answer (score 0):

[image: error start]

it's happening because need commenting the code in main class, im my case

Answer (score 0):

If you have Spring Boot 2 and a parent set to `spring-boot-starter-parent`, then you only need `spring-boot-maven-plugin`, without any other plugins, repackaging etc.

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>
</parent>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                your-custom-config-here if needed
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score -1):

This error is because you are exporting the jar by eclipse.
Soluction: after `mvn clean install`, just to use the jar generated in target folder

Comment: I'm not exporting anything from Eclipse, only using the command-line mvn and still get this error. Also it's bad practice to do `mvn clean install` just to build something, especially for snapshot versions as you will get lots of issues with libraries picking up older versions. That command is used to install something into your local repository; if you are just taking it from the target folder then I don't know why you would need to install it.

Comment: Let's not answer questions without reading them. This has nothing to do with Eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, use eclipse IDE to run create jar file

1. rigth click on your project.
   [image: right click on your project]

2.set Goals is "clean package".
[image: set Goals is "clean package"]

3. just wait a minute and see your paht .jar
   [image: see your path .jar at this]

Comment: I think most people are trying to do this from the command line, without Eclipse. for example to share as technical instructions with people who may or may not have Eclipse installed.

Answer (score -1):

Nothing Needs to be done Extra
Create 2 jars one normal and one fat jar
run normal jar and add dependency jar as a class path while running

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <finalName>main-jar-service</finalName>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>

            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
            </configuration>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>

        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Command to run jar

```
java -cp dependency-jar.jar -jar main-jar-service.jar
```

Comment: That will still include all jars in the spring boot one.

Answer (score -3):

Alternatively, you can use this;

```
click -> run as maven clean
      -> run as maven install 

and your jar in /yourProjectFolder/target/yourProjectName-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 

java -jar yourProjectName-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

Comment: This is about the command line (terminal) so not sure where you are clicking something...