# Gradle build with fatJar plugin and SpringBoot application gives 'Application startup failed'

Tags: gradle, spring-boot, jar

Everything was working fine when starting my app using `Intellij`. But when I made `fatJar` (with gradle plugin: `eu.appsatori.fatjar`) and execute:

```
java -jar myapp.jar
```

I'm getting something like this:

```
11:41:01.224 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [my.testing.MyAppMain]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:482)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:184)
...
```

It looks like it didn't found auto configuration classes in `META-INF/spring.factories`.

How to add this file? And what should be the content of it?

I've got following build script:

```
apply plugin: "java";
apply plugin: "idea";
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'eu.appsatori.fatjar'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.4.3.RELEASE'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
        classpath "eu.appsatori:gradle-fatjar-plugin:0.3"
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/main/java'
        }

        resources {
            srcDir 'src/main/resources'
        }
    }

    test {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/test/java'
        }
    }
}

fatJar {
    manifest {
        attributes("Main-Class": 'my.testing.MyAppMain')
    }

    exclude 'META-INF/*.DSA'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.SF'
    exclude 'META-INF/*.RSA'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'

    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

}
```

And my example code is:

```
package my.testing;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyAppMain {
    private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;

    @Autowired
    private SimpleDao dao;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        MyAppMain test = new MyAppMain();
        try {
            test.init();
            test.doWhatYouGotToDo();
        } finally {
            test.stop();
        }
    }

    private void doWhatYouGotToDo() {
        System.out.println("Auto-wired dao: " + dao.hashCode());
        System.out.println("Auto-wired jdbcTemplate: " + dao.jdbcTemplate.hashCode());
    }

    private void init() throws Exception {
        springContext = SpringApplication.run(MyAppMain.class);
        springContext.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(this);
    }

    private void stop() throws Exception {
        springContext.close();
    }
}

@Component
class SimpleDao {

    @Autowired
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
}
```

`application.properties` file:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/some_db?useSSL=false&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username = some_user
spring.datasource.password = some_pass
```

**NOTE:** This question is based on [SpringBoot - making jar files - No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792031/springboot-making-jar-files-no-auto-configuration-classes-found-in-meta-inf)
where are all answers are referring to building with `Maven`. Please put only answers related to `Gradle` here.

Comment: Don't use the `fatjar` plugin... Spring Boot already creates a fat jar... You now have 2 competing mechanisms....

Comment: So how can I build into a fat jar without that plugin? I.e. how to successfully run above application outside of IntelliJ?

Comment: Ok. Gradle `bootRepackage` task does it. Thanks! You could form an answer so I can accept it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although I mostly use Maven for Spring and Gradle for Android, but here is the gradle way for a Spring project:

```
gradle clean build
gradle bootRepackage
```

Result:

[image]

Here is my build.gradle file:

[image]

Comment: Please share whole build.gradle. I am stuck since 2days

Comment: Choose a Gradle project from here if you want to see an empty gradle file:  https://start.spring.io/