# Spring boot App can't turn on from console as .jar

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

My SpringBoot app works good if I run her from InteliJ, but when I'm trying to open from console as `.jar` I got:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories.

I found just 1 topic on Stack about this, and no helps me [click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792031/springboot-making-jar-files-no-auto-configuration-classes-found-in-meta-inf?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

It is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.location</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-rest-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOTwithIP</version>


    <!-- Define the parent pom -->
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <!-- Set the Java version -->
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <start-class>com.location.restservice.Application</start-class>
    </properties>


    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring Boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JPA Data -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Data REST -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- MySQL Connector-J -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <!-- Spring Boot Maven Plugin -->
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>

                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

What can be wrong ? How I should do ? If u have question, pls ask in comment.

I have `@SpringBootApplication` in main class

Comment: Just remove the repackage goal, and the fork and mainClass configurations and try again. Spring boot will find the right class annotated with @SpringBootApplication

Comment: @Strelok no helps ;/ still this same error

Comment: What’s the JAR name that you’re running? Is your main class annotated with @SpringBootApplication?

Comment: yes, I have annotated, my JAR name is this same as project InteliJ - mysqlrestservice.jar

Comment: How are you running the jar and/or how are you building the jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing this `mvn spring-boot:run`

Comment: in console ?
'mvn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: do you have mvnw.bat file in the project directory

Comment: else install maven and set maven class path

Comment: I dont have, for sure in META-INF or WEB-INF ?

Comment: install maven and try

Comment: BUILD FAILURE after mvn spring-boot:run

Comment: did you executed the cmd in directory where pom.xml is located

Comment: ok, we have progress ! is there only this way to run app  ? why i cannot turn on this from java -jar myapp.jar without mvn ?

Comment: I think if you want to run using java then you have to set required parameters and classpath jars. Intellij automatically set these things for you. if you see the exact cmd(first line in console greyed.click to reveal)  Intellij is executing then you will have idea how to execute.

Comment: @acxz94 my Manifest.mf  have only 1 line with Main-class, maybe here should be something more ?

Comment: I don't think so. This is what intellij executes when I run application - https://pastebin.com/9eGmy9yS.

Answer (score -1):

Ensure that your pom has the following:

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

with these dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.company.common</groupId>
        <artifactId>common-files</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and the following build:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <fork>true</fork>
                <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
            </configuration>
              <executions>
                <execution>
                  <goals>
                    <goal>repackage</goal>
                  </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
          <configuration>
            <archive>
              <manifest>
                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                <mainClass>com.company.mavenproject1.MainClass</mainClass>
              </manifest>
            </archive>
            <descriptorRefs>
              <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
            </descriptorRefs>
          </configuration>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>assemble-all</id>
              <phase>package</phase>
              <goals>
                <goal>single</goal>
              </goals>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Get Maven to update project, as well as snapshots and releases.

Run Maven 'clean install'.

Comment: nothing, still can run app only in InteliJ, from jar this same error

Comment: Don't mess around with the assembly plugin if anything it will make things worse.