# Can't run Spring Boot application trough the command line

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, build, javac

I am trying to run my Spring Boot application through the command line but I am getting this error

```
MigrationsApplication.java:3: error: package org.springframework.boot does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
                               ^
MigrationsApplication.java:4: error: package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure does not exist
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
                                             ^
MigrationsApplication.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
@SpringBootApplication
 ^
  symbol: class SpringBootApplication
MigrationsApplication.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        SpringApplication.run(MigrationsApplication.class, args);
        ^
  symbol:   variable SpringApplication
  location: class MigrationsApplication
4 errors
```

when I try to build it using the command  `javac MigrationsApplication.java`

### pom File

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.migrations</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Migrations</name>
    <description>Demonstration of some migrations</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

### Main Class

```
package com.migrations.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.io.IOException;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MigrationsApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        //if entered the command run in the command line
        SpringApplication.run(MigrationsApplication.class, args);

        //if entered the command create in the command line
        /*MigrationGenerator generator=new MigrationGenerator();
        try {
            generator.generateMigrationFile("TEST2");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("There was an error generating the file");
        }*/
    }

}
```

I also have this "error " Select Run/Debug Configuration
[image]

How can I fix this? Maybe I imported my project from start.io in a wrong way or is it because I don't have Maven installed?

[image: Project structure]

### Updating pom

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.migrations</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>MigrationsApp</name>
    <description>Migrations</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>common-files</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                </configuration>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <mainClass>migrations.MigrationsAppApplication</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>assemble-all</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

[image: Update pom errors]

Comment: Please build first on plain command line and check the file which you are trying to start ... is this the right jar? Also please post how you exactly started the application..

Comment: It wasn't a jar

Answer (score 0):

This will not work. Because If one class is dependent on another class that hasn't been compiled yet, the program won't run

```
  javac *.java // compliles all java files in the dir

  java MigrationsApplication // runs the particular file
```

So you should compile all files before trying to run the program dependent on other files.

If your files are packaged, then something like this

```
javac com.mypackage/.*java

java com.mypackage.MigrationsApplication
```

For Error in your debug configuration, Check what is missing or wrongly provided in the configuration.

Also, I suggest to create a sprint boot project and run it as a Spring boot JAR from the command line either or from the IDE itself

To run it as a JAR:

```
 java -jar target/your.jar
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood, so I must enter my project path and do javac *. java ?

Comment: Updated my question with the project strucuture

Comment: To run my project I should enter the commands 
`cd C:\Users\fabio\Desktop\MigrationsApp`
`javac *.java`
Right?

Comment: No , You should run either the JAR or from IDE itself.  Check Inside Target if there is a JAR. Paste it in any folder and then run  java -jar target/your.jar . 

By doing javac  *.java you are compiling it manually.

Comment: I generated the jar and those erros disappeared but now I am getting `No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.`

Comment: Try this . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792031/springboot-making-jar-files-no-auto-configuration-classes-found-in-meta-inf

Comment: tried the solutin with the most upvotes but I am getting errors in the pom file(updated my question with them)