# Spingboot-No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories when trying to run my jar file

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, jar, liquibase

I compiled my programm in a JAR file but when I try to run it through the command line I get the following error

```
2021-03-07 18:26:02.453  INFO 16780 --- [           main] c.p.migrations.MigrationsApplication     : Starting MigrationsApplication using Java 15.0.2 on LAPTOP-VHVPUD9B with PID 16780 (C:\Users\fabio\Desktop\Migrations\out\artifacts\Migrations_jar\Migrations.jar started by fabio in C:\Users\fabio)
2021-03-07 18:26:02.456  INFO 16780 --- [           main] c.p.migrations.MigrationsApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2021-03-07 18:26:02.770 ERROR 16780 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories. If you are using a custom packaging, make sure that file is correct.
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notEmpty(Assert.java:470) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getCandidateConfigurations(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:180) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector.getAutoConfigurationEntry(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:123) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.AutoConfigurationImportSelector$AutoConfigurationGroup.process(AutoConfigurationImportSelector.java:434) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGrouping.getImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:879) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:330) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:246) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:745) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:563) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:767) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1311) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1300) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
        at com.petapilot.migrations.MigrationsApplication.main(MigrationsApplication.java:17) ~[Migrations.jar:na]
```

I already tried the solutions provided in this question [SpringBoot - making jar files - No auto configuration classes found in META-INF/spring.factories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38792031/springboot-making-jar-files-no-auto-configuration-classes-found-in-meta-inf) but it didn't solve my problem.

### pom File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.petapilot</groupId>
    <artifactId>migrations</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Migrations</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>15</java.version>
        <liquibase.mysql.url>jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306</liquibase.mysql.url>
        <liquibase.mysql.username>root</liquibase.mysql.username>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Can you share any update on the above problem? Were you able to fix it? It has been quite a time since this question was posted.